# No match for call to '(std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>) (unsigned int&, unsigned int)'

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I don't know what's wrong with the follwing code, it should read numbers and put their value with the position together in a vector of pairs and then sort them and print out the positions. I removed the part with sort - i thought the problem was there, but i received an error on compilation again.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                           
#include <vector>                                                                                                             
#include <algorithm>                                                                                                          
#include <utility>                                                                                                            
using namespace std;                                                                                                          

int main(void)
{
        unsigned int n,d,a[65],b[65],s,i,j,t,us=0;
        pair<unsigned int,unsigned int> temp;
        vector< pair<unsigned int,unsigned int> > v;
        cin >> n;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                cin >> t;
                temp(t, i+1);
                v.push_back(temp);
        }
        cin >> d;
        for(i=0;i<d;i++) cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
        for(i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        {
                cout << v[i].first << " -- " << v[i].second << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Please tell me where is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The line numbers in your error messages are important and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `temp(t, i+1);`

You need to set the first and second manually

```
temp.first = t;
temp.second = i + 1;
```

Alternatively you can declare temp inside the loop (probably what I'd do).

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{ 
    cin >> t; 
    pair<unsigned int,unsigned int> temp(t, i+1); 
    v.push_back(temp); 
}
```

Or a second alternate, use the make_pair helper function, and do away with temp completely (thanks to KennyTM for the reminder)

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{ 
    cin >> t; 
    v.push_back(make_pair(t, i+1)); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: or construct the variable in the loop  pair<unsigned int,unsigned int> temp(t, i+1);

Comment: @KennyTM: It's years since I coded C++ in anger, and had forgotten all about make_pair, thanks.

Comment: Vaiols, here's an explanation of the problem: The compiler thought you were trying to call `operator()` on the `temp` variable. It therefore complained that it could find no way to call that operator using parameters of the types mentioned in the error message. Using parentheses to *initialize* a variable is only allowed in the definition (which for local variables is also always the declaration). Attempting that syntax elsewhere will be interpreted as an `operator()` call. The `std::pair` class has no such operator.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally bad form to create a variable outside of a loop and re-use it many times in the loop, if the only place you use it is in that loop. Only do this if the construction cost is high and it's cheaper to re-assign than to re-create. Generally C++ variables should be declared in the scope they are used, to make it easier to read each part of the program and to be able to re-factor it later.

In your case, I would delete the reference to `temp` entirely, and change the push_back call to `v.push_back(make_pair(t, i+1))`.